# Open source the Stack Exchange app and API

Tags: feature-request, api, api-v2.3

It has come to my attention that neither the app nor the API have received much if any attention in the last two years. The latest API is also largely undocumented.

My humble request is to either A) Seriously improve the app and API and fix some serious bugs, which SE devs seem to not want to do, or B) Open source (at least partially) the two. I personally, along with many others on the SE network of sites, would be more than happy to aide in the development of them.

Comment: Some history: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14656/is-the-stack-overflow-source-code-available

Comment: @BrockAdams a little old, and only for stack overflow, but relevant